# Globally Lipschitz implies solutions exist for all time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand when you have a locally lipschitz functiion $f$ for the IVP you are guaranteed the existence and uniqueness of a solution. However this solution may not exist for all time. Why is it that with a globally lipschitz function solutions do exist for all time?

Answer (score 7):

The not so classical proof allows this. Define on the space $C(\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^n)$ of continuous functions the norm
$$
\|y\|_L=\sup_{x\in\Bbb R} e^{-2L\,|x|}·\|y(x)\|
$$
and consider the space of continuous functions that have a finite norm with this formula. This space contains the constant functions.

Then the Picard operator
$$
(P(y))(x)=y_0+\int_0^x f(y(t))\,dt
$$
is contractive, since (restrict for the moment to $x>0$, $x<0$ works exactly the same)
\begin{align}
e^{-2L\,|x|}\left\|(P(y_2))(x)-(P(y_1))(x)\right\|
&\le \int_0^x e^{-2L(x-t)}·e^{-2Lt}·L·\|y_2(t)-y_1(t)\|\,dt
\\
&\le L·\int_0^x e^{-2L(x-t)}\,dt·\|y_2-y_1\|_L
\\
&= \frac12(1-e^{-2L\,x})·\|y_2-y_1\|_L
\end{align}
so that finally
$$
\left\|P(y_2)-P(y_1)\right\|_L\le \frac12·\|y_2-y_1\|_L
$$
Now everything you need is supplied by applying the Banach fixed point theorem and the fact that the image of $P$ is actually in $C^1(\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n)$.

Comment: The norm $\|y\|_L$ may be infinite for some continuous functions; did you mean to restrict to the functions with $\|y\|_L<\infty$?

Comment: Yes of course. And since the constant functions are included, the start of the fixed point iteration is in that space, and consequently also the limit.

Comment: Do i understand correctly, that this variant doesn't give uniqness? Because the fixed point theorem gives the unique fixed point for the space of functions for which this norm is finite and says nothing about uniqness in the larger space of $C^1$ functions.

Comment: @Koncopd : Over any finite interval this norm is equivalent to the supremum norm, and uniquenees, or the non-existence of branching points, is a local property.

Comment: But if for IVP you have a solution on the whole $\mathbb R$ and on every interval it has to be unique, then it has to be unique for the whole $\mathbb R$, no?

Comment: Yes, that follows. But for an IVP to have two solutions, there has to be a branching point, the last point where two solutions are identical. The possibility to branch depends on the local properties of the ODE in a small neighborhood. In that sense uniqueness is a local property, even if you need it locally valid over the whole domain of the ODE.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So to show uniqueness we can use the same proof but restricting the space to arbitrary closed intervals, correct?

Comment: Yes. Or you can circumvent this discussion completely and use the Grönwall lemma. It shows in this context that solutions can only drift away with an exponential factor in time. As the other factor is the distance of the initial points, identical IC give identical solutions.

Comment: ok, i see, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is locally Lipschitz and you are looking to solve $u' = f(u)$ with $u(0) = u_0$, the usual procedure allows you to prove existence (and uniqueness) on an interval $[0,t_0]$ where $t_0$ depends on the Lipschitz constant of $f$ but **not** on $u_0$.

As long as the Lipschitz constant is global you can proceed to finding a solution on $[t_0,2t_0]$, and then $[2t_0,3t_0]$, and so on through all positive times.

Comment: Is there a simple argument for the claim (universal $t_0$)?

Comment: The simple argument is that $t_0$ depends only on the Lipschitz constant, not the initial time or the initial data.

Comment: If the Lipschitz constant is 1, how much is $t_0$ then?

Comment: $t_0 = 1/2$ should do the job.