# Reference - basic ODE global uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

Unless I am very badly mistaken it should hold that any solution $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) of the equation

$$f'(t)=g(f(t)) \quad \quad (t\in [0, \infty))$$
with a given initial condition
$$f(0)=x_0$$

is unique (globally on all of $[0,\infty)$) provided that $g$ is a globally Lipschitz continuous function. However, I don't have an access to a library at the moment and surprisingly I had trouble finding a reference on Google even though it is a fairly basic result. I guess you can get the global uniqueness from the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem which gives me an interval on which the solution is unique whose length should only depend on the Lipschitz constant so I could then glue the unique solutions together to show global uniqueness...But I'd rather use a simple reference to the result I cite above.

Thanks for links to any references (preferably those that can be accessed online but inaccessible books are also OK, I can access a physical library, just not every day).

Comment: [Globally Lipschitz implies solutions exist for all time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236413/globally-lipschitz-implies-solutions-exist-for-all-time) MSE question might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about online, but here's a book reference at least:

In [Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1498702597) by Simmons, this is Theorem B in Section 70, Chapter 13 (what you call $t$ is called $x$ here):

“Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous function that satisfies a Lipschitz condition
$$
|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)| \le K|y_1-y_2|
$$
on a strip defined by $a \le x \le b$ and $-\infty < y < \infty$.
If $(x_0,y_0)$ is any point of the strip, then the initial value problem
$$
y'=f(x,y)
,\qquad
y(x_0)=y_0
$$
has one and only on solution on the interval $a \le x \le b$.”

If you have a globally Lipschitz function (i.e., globally also in $x$, not just in $y$), you can apply this with an arbitrary interval $x \in [a,b]$ to deduce your result.

(The book includes the proof of the theorem, done from scratch with Picard iteration, almost but not exactly like for the local theorem.)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to wait a bit longer before accepting the answer in case I get an online reference. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: Hello! Suppose $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ has a global maximum. Then, according to the MVT, the Lipschitz inequality is always satisfied, independent of the interval $a\leq x\leq b$. Does the quoted theorem then say we have a solution defined for all $x$?

Comment: @sunny: Yes. As I wrote, you can apply the theorem to an arbitrary interval $a \le x \le b$ in order to obtain that conclusion.