# Linear, 1st order ODE with unspecified coefficients on compact interval.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-geometry

The following equation is obeyed by the angle between the integral curves of an orthonormal flat coframe and the unit circle. I would like to have an explicit expression for such an angle in terms of integrals of some general coefficients.

"Let $A(l)$ and $B(l)$ be two smooth, periodic functions of $l\in[0,2\pi)$.  Does there exist a solution for the equation

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi (l)}{\mathrm{d} l}=1+A(l) \cos (\phi (l))+B(l) \sin (\phi (l)),
\end{equation}
$$

with $\phi(0)$ some given constant ?"

The answer is for sure yes but only locally (thanks to the smoothness of $A$ and $B$), but I wish to establish a global result (i.e., for all $l\in[0,2\pi)$). Moreover, is it possible to write down an explicit $\phi(l)$ in terms of integrals of $A(l)$ and $B(l)$ ?

Comment: Isn’t $\phi$ supposed to be periodic as well? I do not connect your verbal description with your ODE.

Comment: @TedShifrin $\phi(l)=\phi(l+2\pi)$, yes.

Comment: So the integral of the RHS from $0$ to $2\pi$ must necessarily be $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, True. The functions $A$ and $B$ are such that this integral vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stronger version of the usual existence and uniqueness theorem states that an ODE has a unique global solution if it is globally Lipschitz (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236413/globally-lipschitz-implies-solutions-exist-for-all-time) for details). This applies to your ODE.