# Autonomous Ordinary Differential Equation: Sufficient conditions for global existence and uniqueness of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a lipschitz vector field $b:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ I consider the autonomous ODE $x'(t)=b(x(t))$.

It has the form $x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$ where $f(t,x(t))=b(x(t))$ is continuous and lipschitz in the second variable (in particular, locally lipschitz in the second variable), so there exists a unique $C^1$ local solution.

What can I say about existence and uniqueness of a $C^1$ global solution $x:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: In your first statement, did you mean that $b$ is globally Lipschitz? Then indeed the domain of every maximal solution is $\Bbb R$. Uniqueness is always a local property, in the contrary case there would have to be a branching point.

Comment: Yes, I mean that $b$ is globally lipschitz.

But what is a sufficient condition for global existence and uniqueness of a $C^1$ solution of the ODE $x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$?

Comment: It is the same. If you have a global Lipschitz constant in state direction, then every solution extends to the whole of $\Bbb R$. See [general statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771929/115115) -> [details](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1236482/115115)

Comment: So if $f$ is globally continuous and it is globally lipschitz in the second variable there exists a unique $C^1$ global solution defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$, correct?

Can I conclude that the set of the trajectories (t,x(t)) fill the whole $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, that too, the statement is valid for any initial point.