# Lipschitz continuity of $e^{\sin}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

We want to use the Picard-Lindelöf-Theorem to show that the ODE

$$y'=\mathrm{e}^{\sin(ty)}$$

has a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$ with the initial value $y(0)=0$. As far as I know, we have to show that the right hand side is Lipschitz-continuous with respect to $y$. So we need to proof

$$\vert \mathrm{e}^{\sin(tx)}-\mathrm{e}^{\sin(ty)}\vert \leq L \vert x-y\vert$$
for all $t,x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. I don't get it, to show this. I heard that because the right hand side is differentiable, that is eventually possible to show this with the mean-value theorem or gradient. But I don't know whether this works because I think the derivative is not bounded. What can one do?

Comment: What makes you think that the derivative is not bounded?

Comment: @A.Γ. We have $\vert \partial_y f(t,y)\vert = \vert t \cos(ty)\mathrm{e}^{\sin(ty)}\vert$ and then we can make $t$ arbitrarily large? Or is this not allowed?

Comment: But it *is* bounded on $[0,T]$ for every $T>0$.

Comment: @A.Γ. So $t$ is fixed, as I understand. Ok, it is bounded. How does the rest of the argumentation work? The boundary constant is $t\mathrm{e}$, right?

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. Say that the function is uniformly Lipschitz on $[0,T]$ and use the [global version](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771929/253273) of the theorem. Then say that $T$ is arbitrary. or 2. Prove existence of a solution on $[0,+\infty)$ using $|y'(t)|\le e$ (no blow-up) and then use the local version of the theorem to prove uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual hypothesis required by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, if I am not mistaken, is: for every pair $(t,y)$, there exists some open intervals $t \ in I$, $y \in J$ and some constant $K > 0$, such that if $t’ \in I$ and $y’,y’’ \in J$, $|e^{\sin(ty’)}-e^{\sin(ty’’)}| \leq K|y’-y’’|$.

(ie the function is locally Lipschitz continuous wrt y).

So here, you take $I=]t-1,t+1[$, $J=\mathbb{R}$, and recall that $u \longmapsto e^{\sin(su)}$ is $e|s|$-Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: How do you show the Lipschitz-continuity?

Comment: The $\sin$ function has its range in $[-1,1]$ and is $1$-Lipschitz continuous, and $x \longmapsto e^x$ is $e$-Lipschitz continuous on $(-\infty,1]$.