# Why does Picard-Lindelöf give us only a LOCAL unique solution?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm referring to the Picard-Lindelöf theorem in the form below (from Wikipedia). I understand the proof using the contraction mapping theorem and I understand why we need the to restrict the interval to $[t_0 - \varepsilon, t_0 + \varepsilon]$ for the proof to work. However, I don't understand why it is false that there exists a global unique solution to the initial value problem under the conditions of the theorem. In other words, can someone give a counterexample to the stronger "Probably False Theorem" below?

**Picard-Lindelöf Theorem:**
Consider the initial value problem $$y ′ ( t ) = f ( t , y ( t ) ) ,\ y ( t_0 ) = y_0.$$
Suppose  $f$  is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in $y$ (meaning the Lipschitz constant can be taken independent of $t$) and continuous in $t$, then for some value $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a unique solution $y(t)$ to the initial value problem on the interval $[ t_0 − \varepsilon , t_0 + \varepsilon ]$.

**Probably False Theorem:**
Consider the initial value problem $$y ′ ( t ) = f ( t , y ( t ) ) ,\ y ( t_0 ) = y_0.$$
Suppose  $f$  is uniformly Lipschitz continuous in $y$ (meaning the Lipschitz constant can be taken independent of $t$) and continuous in $t$, then there exists a unique solution $y(t)$ to the initial value problem on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The global version is stated e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771929/42969

Comment: One usually proves that the $\varepsilon$ only depends on the Lipschitz constant. If your $f$ is globally lipschitz, then you can patch such intervals of existence together to show that there exists a global solution.