# Questions about the existence and uniqueness of solutions (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we use the Picard approximation to prove the existence and uniqueness of the solutions, we can only get the solution defined on a finite close interval. But for the equations with constant coefficient, the solution($e^{\lambda t}$) exists and is unique over the whole $R$, how can we change the Picard theorem to prove such a statement or any other theorems. Appreciate your helping hands.

Comment: Maybe this wikipedia article answers you question partially: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Global_uniqueness_and_maximum_domain_of_solution

Comment: I would answer the same as in this older question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2771929/115115, note that linear DE with constant coefficients have a global Lipschitz constant independent of time.

Comment: Picard's theorem gives you some explicit formula for the time of existence, which is expressed in terms of bounds on the function and Lipschitz constants and what-not. For linear ODEs (or slightly more generally, ODEs which satisfy a Lipschitz condition of the type $\|F(t,x_1)-F(t,x_2)\|\leq c(t)\|x_1-x_2\|$, where $F,c$ are continuous), you can use this extra control over the constants to derive a contradiction if you assume finite time of existence (basically assume the existence time is finite, and then use the explicit formula to show there is a proper extension of the solution).

Comment: The details can be found for example in [Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf) Chapter 6, Theorem 1.4 (page 270)