# Approximation of coupled differential equations with recursive integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation

I am currently reading the book "the quantum theory of light" 
link: [http://rplab.ru/~as/2000%20-%20R.Loudon%20-%20The%20Quantum%20Theory%20of%20Light%20-%203rd%20ed%20Oxford%20Science%20Publications.pdf](http://rplab.ru/%7Eas/2000%20-%20R.Loudon%20-%20The%20Quantum%20Theory%20of%20Light%20-%203rd%20ed%20Oxford%20Science%20Publications.pdf) 
In the beginning of chapter 2.3 (page 52) is talked about an approximation method for the differential equations
$$
Vcos(wt)e^{-iw_0t}C_2(t)=i\dot{C_1}(t)\\
Vcos(wt)e^{iw_0t}C_1(t)=i\dot{C_2}(t)
$$
The approximation goes like this:

1. Insert the starting conditions into the left side of the equations. (here $C_1(0)=1$, $C_2(0)=0$)
2. Integrate the modified equations over time on both sides (from $0$ to $t$. So $\int_0^tdt$ on both sides). The result will be an expression for $C_1(t)$ and $C_2(t)$
3. Take the expressions and insert them into the left sides of the initial differential equations.
4. Integrate over time.....

If this process is done and infinitely then the result will be the exact solution of the differential equations. 
My question now: Can this be proven?/ Has this been proven somewhere? I was trying to prove it myself but I was not quite able to. Is this maybe a common approximations for differential equations that is often used?

Comment: This is called Picard iteration; the fact that it converges for small enough $t$ is a standard theorem called the Picard-Lindelof theorem. It converging for any $t$ is a more case-specific thing.

Comment: Linear DE systems $\dot x(t)=A(t)x(t)$ with $\|A(t)\|\le L$ are automatically globally Lipschitz and thus have global solutions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347599/questions-about-the-picard-lindelöf-theorem and links from there. Generally linear DE with the highest order derivative explicit have solutions that exist (at least) on the largest interval where the coefficients are continuous and that contains the initial point.

Comment: Global Lipschitz still doesn't imply global convergence of Picard iteration. It just implies you can buy the same amount of time each time you reinitialize the process.

Comment: thank you all :)