# Suppose $f$ is Lipschitz. Show that every solution to $x^{\prime}=f(x)$ exists on $(-\infty, \infty)$; that is, no solutions blow up in finite time.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, dynamical-systems

Suppose that $f$ is Lipschitz on $U=\mathbf{R}^n$. Show that every solution to $x^{\prime}=f(x)$ exists on $(-\infty, \infty)$; that is, no solutions blow up in finite time.

If the function blows up then $\lim_{t \to c} x(t)=\infty$ then $x(t)=p(t-c)+\frac{c_{-k}}{(t-c)^k}+O(\frac 1{(t-c)^{k+1}}),$ for some $ k \in \Bbb N$ s.t $c_{-k}\neq 0$ and where p is a polynomial, then $x'(t)=p'(t-c)-\frac{kc_{-k}}{(t-c)^{k+1}}+O(\frac 1{(t-c)^{k+2}})=f$ then I thought that $f$ can't be Lipscitz but we have to write $p'(t-c)-\frac{kc_{-k}}{(t-c)^{k+1}}+O(\frac 1{(t-c)^{k+2}})$ in terms of $x$ hence this method won't work.

I feel the question is simple. Can you help?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347599/questions-about-the-picard-lindelöf-theorem-for-an-ode, the links in my answer there, and generally the [search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%5Bode%5D+global*+lipschitz+existence+picard) for a list of relevant keywords

Answer (score 1):

We have the estimate (for $t>t_0$)
$$|x(t)|=|x(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t f(x(s)) ds| \leq |x(t_0)|+\int_ {t_0}^t (L|x(s)| +|f(0)|) ds=|x(t_0)|+(t-t_0)|f(0)|+L\int_ {t_0}^t |x(s)| ds$$
where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$. So by [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality)
$$|x(t)| \leq (|x(t_0)|+(t-t_0)|f(0)|)e^{L(t-t_0)}$$
and therefore $x(t)$ cannot blow up at any finite time $t>t_0$. A similar argument shows that $x(t)$ is defined in $(-\infty, t_0]$.